# Api development with zend framework

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I need to develop the api's for my existing application, ie I have run both standalone application and api for mobile apps from one code base. Application is developed using ZF2. But when considering api development I have to keep in mind about the versonisation of it. So in ZF2 how we can achieve. By creating seperate module for each version or single module which will serve different version? I am cofused.  I am thinking about the below structure

```
module 
----->Application
          -------> Config
          -------> language 
          -------> src
                    -------> Application
                               ------> Controller
                               -------> Models
                               -------> Views
                               -------> Service
                   --------> Webservice
                               ---------> V1
                                           ---> Controller
                                           ---> Models
                               ---------> V2
                                           ----> Controller
                                           ----> Models
```

Comment: You could take a look at integrating [ZF-Apigility](https://apigility.org/documentation/recipes/apigility-in-an-existing-zf2-application). Can't really help you any further as I've no experience with integrating it into an exesting project, but you might give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

I've been following next structure

```
module/Application/
module/UserApi/V1/JsonRpc/UserResource.php
module/SnippetApi/V2/Rest/TagResource.php
module/SnippetApi/V1/Rest/SnippetResource.php
```

Hope it helps